# Convert dateTime.iso8601 value to human readable date in Ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime

I am playing around with the Red Hat Satellite API. One of the values being returned for an API call is `dateTime.iso8601 "last_checkin" - Last time server successfully checked in`. I'm not sure how to parse this, though.

This is the code that returns the data:

```
systems.each do |system|
    print "#{system["name"]}" + " " + "#{system["last_checkin"]}" + "\n"
end
```

It gives a hash back: `#<XMLRPC::DateTime:0x97102d8>`. At least, I think that's a hash.

What do I need to do to look inside it and extract useful information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s not a `Hash`, that’s an instance of class [`XMLRPC::DateTime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/xmlrpc/rdoc/XMLRPC/DateTime.html). Use it’s methods to get printable values, e.g.:

```
systems.each do |system|
  system = system["last_checkin"] # or whatever value you are interested in
  puts "#{system.mon}-#{system.day}-#{system.year}"
end
```

Also please avoid using `"a"+"b"` string concatenation; there is inplace-evaluation ruby paradigm for that (`"#{val}"`.)

Comment: Gotcha. I appear to have been mixing methodologies by using the interpolation with concatenation. Also, I see what you are talking about with the dateTime value. I have simply applied the different methods to it and have extracted useful information. Thanks.